# draw QImage in QQuickWindow::beforeRendering

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qimage

The goal is to implement a video player with a GUI. The GUI is driver by QML, the decoded video frames arrive from an external (non-C++) library.

I’ve got the QML script running (QQmlApplicationEngine). QQmlApplicationEngine::rootObjects returns with a list of objects, the first one is cast to QQuickWindow and a slot is connected to the QQuickWindow::beforeRendering() signal. It works as expected.

I can create a QImage from the raw pixel buffer returned by the video decoder library. Somehow I'd like to make that QImage visible in the QQuickWindow::beforeRendering() signal handler. If my assumption is right then the QML contents will be painted afterwards, so this way I get a video player with a GUI.

My questions:

1. how can I draw QImage in beforeRendering slot?
2. according to my observations QQuickWindow::beforeRendering() is only emitted when something in the QML scene changes (time to re-render). Can I somehow force QQuickWindow/QQmlApplicationEngine to re-render the scene? This is needed in cases where the GUI doesn't change, but a new decoded video frame is available and has to be shown...

(I'm a beginner in Qt)

Thanks

Comment: Take a look to [this tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html) for `beforeRendering()` usage.

Comment: I knew this tutorial; it's more complex than I need. I'd like to avoid OpenGL programming (if possible). I think it's a kind of overkill to play with OpenGL just to display a simple bitmap...

Comment: Perhaps QPainter can be used for this purpose... I haven't examined yet.

Comment: Well then, I think [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.1/qtquick/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html#mixing-scene-graph-and-opengl) and the related links could provide some usuful information.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured it out, thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was on the wrong path towards the solution. The correct approach whick worked for me was to create a new QML item, which is then placed in the QML file. The class for the new QML item is reponsible for drawing the item itself and this is where the decoded video frame comes into the picture. As the renderer of custom QML item works on an FBO, I can use something like this to paint:

```
QOpenGLPaintDevice device(renderSize);
QPainter painter(&device);

painter.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 200), QColor(0, 255, 0));
painter.end();
update();
```

It's not going to be a problem to display any kind of bitmap from memory.

This is the link to a sample code which was a key to the solution:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.1/qtquick/scenegraph-textureinsgnode.html

And some further interesting links:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.1/qtquick/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html#mixing-scene-graph-and-opengl

http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/11/20/qt-weekly-20-completing-the-offering-qopenglwindow-and-qrasterwindow/